# Компонент для вывода блока информации

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, компоненты, модули

Есть сайт [w3layouts](https://w3layouts.com/template/publication-a-corporate-blogging-category-website-template/), [demo](https://demo.w3layouts.com/demos_new/template_demo/30-04-2020/publication-liberty-demo_Free/1014263797/web/index.html?_ga=2.10170935.389158234.1643541675-1945748479.1640607858).
Есть блок на сайте, в котором нет ссылок, кроме иконок социальных сетей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```html
<section id="author" class="w3l-author py-5">
  <div class="container py-lg-3">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-7 order-first">
        <div class="author-image">
          <img src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH ?>/assets/images/main-author.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12 order-md-first mt-lg-0 mt-4">
        <span class="category">Person of the Week</span>
        <h2 class="mt-2 mb-3 title">Hello!! I'm Gwen Johnson </h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam beatae, assumenda ab voluptates maxime non iusto ullam aut veniam reiciendis neque autem at earum ea nam <a href="#url">this is the url link</a> quam quae sed quis iste alias. Adipisci,
          itaque! Voluptatum aliquid rem deleniti? Accusantium inventore eaque odio vero hic officia? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, maiores?
        </p>
        <ul class="author-icons mt-4">
          <li><a class="facebook" href="#url"><span class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> </li>
          <li><a class="twitter" href="#url"><span class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
          <li><a class="google" href="#url"><span class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
          <li><a class="linkedin" href="#url"><span class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
          <li><a class="github" href="#url"><span class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
          <li><a class="dribbble" href="#url"><span class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Какой компонент битрикса можно использовать для этого блока, кроме `news` и `news.list`?

Answer (score 0):

Если данные хранятся в инфоблоке, то `news.detail` (нужно будет передать ID элемента в параметры компонента). Если данные хранить в файле - можно использовать включаемые области (`main.include`).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).